# разбиение списка на несколько частей

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

У меня есть список:

```
[65,40,30,45,45,5,60,45,30,30,45,60,60,45,30,30,60,30,30]
```

и я хотел бы разбить на подсписки на следующих условиях:

1. Сумма значений 2n подсписков всегда должна быть 180
2. Сумма значений 2n+1 подсписков всегда должна быть в интервале  180<=sum<240

Пример вывода:

```
[[65,40,30,45],[60,45,45,30,30,30],[60,60,30,30],[45,45,30,60,5]]
```

или например:

```
[[60,45,30,45],[65,40,45,30,30,30],[60,60,60],[45,45,30,30,30,5]]
```

кол-во входных значений N, но мы также знаем, что значений всегда достаточно, чтобы сформировать подсписки т.е не получится ситуации,когда значение не попадет ни в один подсписок. Порядок случайный и не важен для нас, главное выполнить условия. Я так думаю это своего рода подбрасывание монетки, мы будем разбивать случайным образом столько раз пока не будут соблюдены условия.

Если я не прав то подскажите пожалуйста оптимальный алгоритм?

И если есть идеи как это сделать на Python(может какая-нибудь есть библиотека готовая для таких задач)?

Comment: Что означает `2n` и `2n+1` здесь?

Answer (score 1):

Заинтересовала задачка.
Если я правильно понял условие, то решение может быть таким:

```
import itertools
lst = [65,40,30,45,45,5,60,45,30,30,45,60,60,45,30,30,60,30,30]

lim=round(sum(lst)/210)
p = [list(x) for x in set(itertools.combinations(lst, int(len(lst)/lim)))]
res_even = [x for x in p if sum(x) == 180][:int(lim/2)]
for i in res_even:
    for j in i:
        lst.remove(j)
res_odd = [lst[:int(len(lst)/2)],lst[int(len(lst)/2):]]

for i,val in enumerate(res_odd):
    res_even.insert(2*i+1,val)

print(res_even)
```

> [[45, 45, 45, 45], [65, 40, 5, 30, 60], [30, 30, 60, 60], [45, 30, 30, 60, 30, 30]]

Answer (score 0):

```
def func() :
    list_initial = [65 , 40 , 30 , 45 , 45 , 5 , 60 , 45 , 30 , 30 , 45 , 60 , 60 , 45 , 30 , 30 , 60 , 30 , 30]
    list_final , list_even , list_odd = [] , [] , []
    for n in list_initial :
        n % 2 == 0 if list_even.append(n) else list_odd.append(n)
    tmp = []
    for n_o in list_odd :
        if sum(tmp) == 180 :
            list_final.append(tmp)
            tmp=[]
        else :
            tmp.append(n_o)
    tmp = []
    for n_e in list_even :
        if 180 <= sum(tmp) <= 240 :
            list_final.append(tmp)
            tmp=[]
        else :
            tmp.append(n_e);
    return list_final
```

Можно разбивать и в случайном порядке но не вижу смысла (или это тоже условие ?).

Что сделано:

1. Делим элементы на четн\нечет
2. Проходим по двум новым спискам и формируем финальный список согласно условию

Результат: `[[65, 40, 30, 45], [65, 40, 30, 45], [5, 60, 45, 30, 30, 45], [60, 45, 30, 30, 60]]`

И ответ на вопрос про библиотеки:
Я подозреваю что [numPy](http://www.numpy.org/) может помочь с более оптимальным алгоритмом.